# why isn't all maclaurin series undefined at 0

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

every maclaurin series contains $$\frac{f^0(0)\cdot x^0}{0!}$$ well, at $x=0 \rightarrow x^0=0^0=0^1\cdot 0^{-1}=\frac{0}{0}$ which has no **arithmetic** meaning. I understand it is indeterminate, but  we are not talking limits here because it is at a discrete integer $n=0$. I understand that we want the first term to evaluate to a constant but wouldn't this issue be avoided by rewriting it as?:

$$S=f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^n(0)\cdot x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: In the sum notation, $x^0$ is understood to mean $1$. It’s a matter of notational convenience, so you can write the series as a single summation. It’s called a “convention”, and it’s preferable to the one you give because it’s easier to work with/manipulate.

Comment: $0^0=1{{}}{}{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Hardly a universally agreed-upon meaning, though there are certainly some good arguments for it...

Comment: In fact, it’s not just MacLauren series; this is the case in *any* power series. We write them as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x-r)^n$, with the understanding that at $n=0$ the summand is to be understood to be equal to $a_0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, thank you. But it is technically an issue, just not worth pointing out...?

Comment: It’s an issue that should have been agreed on as a convention when you first encounter the sigma notation for power series. Once that is noted, then it is no longer worth pointing out, because everyone who is using the notation is supposed to understand what it means.

Comment: Your mistake is $\ 0^0 = 0^1 * 0^{-1}\ $ because the two sides are **not** equal. Please read Wikipedia [zero to the power zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) for a lot of information.

Comment: Your link even says it has no agreed upon value. Sure, it may not be a completely legitimate equation but it gets the point across that it is undefined